# Attiny13 project with leds and electret microphone

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny, led-strip

I want to make a project similar to this [Turn Signal Biking Jacket](http://www.instructables.com/id/turn-signal-biking-jacket/)

[image: Turn Signal Biking Jacket].

But, instead of using Arduino Lilypad I want to use an 8 pin [attiny13A-SH](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATtiny13A) and want to use one [electret microphone](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8635) instead of the buttons.

I want to use led's only for the left, right and a stop indicator(on the back, i don't want the leds on the sides like the instructable project).

According to me, the leds require 1 pin each and will share a common gnd(that's 4 pins).

The microphone will require 1 additional pin, with 1 going to the gnd (5 pins).

And I might require 2 pins for the power outlet (6 pins out of 8).

Now, i am a newbie in all this stuff so i don't want to go about experimenting with the chips. I am ready to disable the reset pin cause i wont require the chip again. I have got a couple of instructable's to help me in the programming and set-up plan(though they have used Arduino Uno or Lilypad), so **I only want to know if it is possible to make the project with the attiny13a chip without the requirement of any additional parts.**

Also, as an alternative, i wanted to use [these leds](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/0-5M-1M-2835-SMD-RGB-Led-Strip-Light-60Leds-M-DC-12V-Non-Waterproof-Kitchen/32767999594.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.16.6df854bcWWLDT1&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_10342_10343_10340_10341_10084_10083_10618_10307_5711211_5722315_10313_10059_10534_100031_10629_10103_10626_10625_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620_10142,searchweb201603_2,ppcSwitch_5_ppcChannel&algo_expid=6432d851-7fac-4c64-9ee5-6d40405fbdc9-2&algo_pvid=6432d851-7fac-4c64-9ee5-6d40405fbdc9&priceBeautifyAB=0) instead of the lilypad led's, so i want to know if i can do the model in exactly the same way without using any mofsets etc(i just want 6 leds on each side). I'm extremely sorry for my horrible drawing(First time and no correct tools. used paint!)[image] 
**ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED.**

Answer (score 1):

> want to use 1 electret microphone instead of the buttons.

In what way do you want to use the microphone? You do realise, don't you, that an Arduino can't understand speech (or much of anything really) without powerful extra hardware? A microphone by itself is pretty much useless, especially without any form of preamp and signal conditioning.

> i only want to know if it is possible to make the project with the attiny13a chip without the requirement of any additional parts.

No, it's not possible. You will require lots more parts. You can't just take an arbitrary chip and connect it to a battery and expect it to work properly. You need to consider correct supply voltages (voltage regulation or boosting depending on your power source), decoupling capacitors, drive circuitry, amplification, signal processing, etc...

> i wanted to use these leds instead of the lilypad led's, so i want to know if i can do the model in exactly the same way without using any mofsets etc

Again, no.  Those are 12V LED strips. You need both a 12V supply (and the associated regulation down to 5V to power the ATTiny etc) and MOSFETs (or something similar) to allow the ATTiny to switch that 12V to the LED strips as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I didn't get your point on the microphone thing since there are loads of voice controlled leds tutorials on the net which use the same mic and the bitvoicer software

Comment: Are you going to carry your PC around with you on your bike?

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer would be "**No, it's not possible**"

You cannot run a single chip independently without any protection and regulating components(e.g. capacitor, regulator, current limiting resistor)

Also by replacing components with other ones, it would require you additional adjustments in the code and also in the hardware(Referring to the replacing buttons with Electret Microphone). There is a reason for the Arduino Lilypad to have additional components so that it can run smoothly and avoid damages to both the user and the device itself.

Comment: There are many Tut's on making our own custom Arduino which uses a chip and a capacitor or something. Can I make it like that on a custom based pcb(the chip)

Comment: Yes, you could make that, providing that you will use the required necessary basic components. I see that the size matters to you so I would recommend you to try to look also into other Arduino compatible boards like this one here from Adafruit , the [Gemma](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1222)(which is at the size of a Quarter!) and [Flora](https://www.adafruit.com/product/659).